# "Famous" Jewish painting "The Talmud" pedigree

Tags: history, art

I have a painting I inherited from my grandparents that I have seen reproduced elsewhere by seemingly other artists, with some variations. The scene depicts a number of rabbis/scholars around a table in a *Beis Medrash* arguing over some text. I'll post an example below.

This has intrigued me for some time. Does anyone know the original source of this painting? Who the original artist was? What the background of this painting is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I vote to re-open this post, as it is clearly about a depiction of Judaism, per se, not just of Jews.

Comment: @IsaacMoses It's not about Judaism. It's about art. It would be better suited for an Art SE, if it existed. (I don't think it does.)

Comment: "Who painted it" isn't about Judaism, but I suppose the "background to the painting" is related to Judaism

Comment: @ezra It's about art about Judaism. Other potential SE sites are irrelevant. Is it reasonable to expect people who know about Judaism to have an advantage at knowing about this painting? Yes.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No, it's not about Judaism. It's about who painted it, who may or may not have been a Jew. (I'm pretty sure Schleicher was Jewish though.) To give you a better understanding of what I'm saying, asking "What are the rabbis doing in this painting?" would be on-topic, but in this case the OP is asking who originally painted it, so it's decidingly OFF-topic.

Comment: @ezra “Does anyone know the original source of this painting” and “what the background of this painting is” are clearly on-topic for the reasons Isaac states. You seem to only be arguing on “who the original artist was.” Why not suggest to delete that one line and leave it open, rather than shut down two good questions because of one that doesn’t fit?

Answer (score 12):

The painting is called *[Eine Streitfrage aus dem Talmud](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carl_Schleicher_Eine_Streitfrage_aus_dem_Talmud.jpg)* (A Talmudic Dispute) by Carl Schleicher. It was painted sometime during the 19th Century in Germany. Here are [some other works](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Carl_Schleicher) by him. I could not find much about him on English webpages, but here is a [Wikipedia article in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Schleicher).

Comment: Thank you Ezra. I'm wondering if that rendering is the original piece or a reproduction. I've edited my question to show two variants of the same theme. My question is whose is the original?

Comment: @ShmuelBrown [You can clearly see that the second is from a later period...]

Comment: @dr.shmuel I wasn't asking specifically between those two variants, it was for illustrative purposes (see what I did there?). There are numerous variants of that scene - of differing qualities/styles - and I want to know where it originated.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for the original artist of this painting. 
There is an article  by Zola Levitt, (1995) which has the picture as an illustration  and the rubric:  "oil on panel by Carl Schleicher (1825-1903)".

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! As it may be different than other sites you’re used to, please see our [tour] for more information about how MY works. Your post here seems better suited as a comment rather than an answer; once you have enough reputation you’ll be able to comment on any post you’d like.

Comment: @Oscar Ferreira - I have edited your answer so that the key valuable information is not lost in your personal narrative. You can always roll back the edit.